# ValueError: could not convert string to float in dictionary

Tags: python, string

I'm converting a long dictionary of weekly values into monthly values.

Here is a small sample of the dict:

```
weeklydic={'2007-10-21': '56', '2007-10-28': '58', '2011-07-10': '56', '2011-07-16': '56'}
```

I'm using this code to sum the weekly values of the same month:

```
monthlydic = {}

for key in weeklydic:  
    k = key[0:7]  
    if (k in weeklydic):  
        monthlydic[k] += float(weeklydic[key])  
    else:  
        monthlydic[k] = float(weeklydic[key])
```

In general it is working fine, in this small sample it should return

```
monthlydic={'2007-10': '114', '2011-07': '112'}
```

However in one dictionary apparently there is a value that I cannot convert to float, so I'm getting this very annoying message:

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float
```

My questions are:

a) Is there a way I can track the wrong item of the dictionary to better understand what is happening?

b) Is there a way I can convert that "if statement" to a "try statement" in a way that it passes by any errors?

Comment: I just ran what you posted and it doesn't return what you have in your sample output. First, the values in your `monhtlydic` are strings... Anyways, I think you meant `if k in monthlydic:`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple of sugestions.

First, use a defaultdict which saves the initial check for a key. Second, convert to float with try, and return None if not a float.

Whenever None is encountered, save this to a list.

```
from collections import defaultdict

def convert_float(x):
    try:
        return float(x)
    except:
        return None

monthlydic = defaultdict(float)
problems = []

for key in weeklydic:  
    k = key[0:7]  
    val = convert_float(weeklydic[key])
    if val is not None:
        monthlydic[k] += val
    else:  
        problems.append((k, weeklydic[key]))
```

Comment: The `defaultdict` is nice and saves a line of code and potential bugs. I prefer the other solution that reports the exception that was caught- it's not fun to be faced with a list of 'problems' with no idea of which keys they were thrown for, or even which exceptions were actually thrown. May later forget to check the `problems` list too. Depending on the application it may be better to have the exception terminate it than to soldier on with invalid data.

Comment: Worked fine Kevin, thanks. However I also need to track where is the problematic item. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

```
weekly_string = weeklydic[key]
try:
    weekly_float = float(weekly_string)
except ValueError as e:
    print('error={error}, key={key}, value="{value}"'.format(
          error=e, key=key, value=weekly_string))
    weekly_float = 0.0
```

You only need to do this once before, not for both branches of your `if: else:`

Comment: I'm getting this: could not convert string to float: , " ". Do you know what does it mean?

Comment: It means that your dictionary likely has a bad value in it, something like: `weeklydic={'2007-10-21': ' ', ... }`. To help you debug you could also print out the `key` in that `except` block.

Comment: It means the value is a space `" "`. `float(" ")` gives that error.